# How to create nested folders and file in Context.MODE_PRIVATE?

Tags: java, android, file-io

I have a requirement where files and folders are required to be written in nested structure using `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

I found that we can create file using `openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and was able to create files using this method.But later on I found that using this method I can not create a nested file structure i.e for

```
openFileOutput("foo/myText.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File foo/myText.txt contains a path separator
```

May be because it expects only a `fileName & not a filepath` and also documentation says

> Open a private file associated with this Context's application package
>   for writing.

Then I found that `getFilesDir()` returns Context's application package where I can create files using the normal Java File I/O.But I don't know the permissions under which it is created i.e whether it is `MODE_APPEND`,`MODE_PRIVATE`,`MODE_WORLD_READABLE` or `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`.

So, I have following questions:-

1. How do I create nested file structure using openFileOutput() method under MODE_PRIVATE(if it's possible)?
2. If openFileOutput() is not applicable to create a nested structure,then is it safe to use `getFilesDir()` and Java File I/O combination for my requirement? What is the permission for the files created using this way?

Answer (score 6):

***You need to create `foo` directory first then create file inside that dir.***

*Use [getDir(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to create directory into internal memory. The method **Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own custom data files. You can use the returned File object to create and access files in this directory.***

---

*For example*

```
// Create directory into internal memory;
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Get a file myfile within the dir mydir.
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); 
// Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
```

---

*So your need to write your code as*

```
// Create foo directory into internal memory;
File mydir = getDir("foo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Get a file myText.txt within the dir foo.
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myText.txt"); 
// Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*to create foo/myText.txt into internal storage.*

---

For nested directories, you should use normal java method. Like

```
new File(parentDir, "childDir").mkdir();
```

***So updated example should be***

```
// Create directory into internal memory;
File mydir = getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Create sub-directory mysubdir
File mySubDir = new File(mydir, "mysubdir");
mySubDir.mkdir();

// Get a file myfile within the dir mySubDir.
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mySubDir, "myfile"); 
// Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
```

Comment: i don't think above way can be used generically in all scenarios. it compels me to parse the file path and pass each sub-directory one by one.

What if i have four levels of nested folder,say `f1/f2/f3/f4/myText.txt`??

I am looking for something equivalent to 
`File f = new File("f1/f2/f3/f4/myText.txt");
     if(!f.getParentFile().exists()){
      f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
     }`

Comment: There is no way... AFIK.

Comment: thnx for the work around..however can you please answer my two questions that I asked above?

Comment: @Abhinav Hello, yes sure.. 1. No, as I said previously you can't. 2. All the file related classes are from java only, look there path. So no worry about Java/ Android file. And you are not required to add any permission for that. Hope I answered well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public OutputStream openFile(String absolutePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
  File file = new File(absolutePath);
  new File(file.getParent()).mkdirs();

  return new FileOutputStream(absolutePath);
}

public OutputStream openInternalFile(String relativePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
  String rootPath = this.getFilesDir().getPath();
  File file = new File(rootPath, relativePath);
  return openFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This is what I came up which covers your use case. You can either pass the `absolutePath` or `relativePath`. behind the scene it does create a nested folders inside internal storage and returns back an `OutputStream` which you can start write into it.