# How to hide the file from user in android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an android application and I want to hide the downloaded data just like youtube does when you download the video.

Also I want the access to the downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

You should store those files in internal app storage. 
You can find extended explanation in https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 0):

Use file directory as MODE_PRIVATE

```
File mydir = mContext.getDir("vlurb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;       
String outPutFileRecord = mydir+ "/" + "AudioRecording.mp3";
```

Stored inside app data. You can access through `DeviceFileExplorer` bottom right of the Android studio `data`->`data`->
[image: example 1]

`applicationId` folder

[image: example 2]

Refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21326537/12830957) for more

Comment: How do I get it to download it directly on this folder ?

Comment: don't worry it will when you call this method